# Make OnClose event run when clicking outside dialog box with dismissableMask set true

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a dialog box that accepts user input and runs a function on closing of the dialog box. Using primeng dynamic dialog component. This function is called during the onClose event. This works fine with a close button.

I have dispossable mask on to allow user to close box by clicking outside of it. Here the onClose event doesnt fire. Is there any way to capture the event where user clicks outside the box or to make onClose fire?

> https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/dynamicdialog

component 1

```
addQuoteDialog() {
    let selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();

    const ref = (this.addQuoteDialogRef = this.dialogService.open(
      AddQuoteDialogComponent,
      {
        width: '95%',
        styleClass: 'user-details',
        showHeader: false,
        //contentStyle: { 'max-height': '500px', overflow: 'auto' },
        height: '70',
        data: {
          selectedData: selectedData,
        },
        dismissableMask: true,
      }
    ));
    ref.onClose.subscribe((response) => {
      ref.destroy();
    });
    return ref;
  }
```

component 2

```
  onClose() {
    console.log('onclose');
    this.quoteDisplayFalse();
    this.ref.close();
  }
```

Comment: Where is the OnClose (component 2) referenced? Clicking outside the dialog area will trigger the ref.onClose subscription in component 1.

Answer (score 0):

Add a console after "ref.onClose.subscribe((response) => { ". You will get the console being logged when you click outside the box. Here, you can also write another function being called upon close.

No need to do ref.destroy, as it will automatically close the dialog box.